# Angular directive with jquery event only firing once

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a directive that only fires once and only when you start on the page with the directive.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML -

```
<div class="body">
    <a href="#/systems"><div class="viewBySys"></div></a>
        <div ng-view class="container reveal-animation"></div>
    <a href="#/applications"><div class="viewByAppl"></div></a>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="appls.html">
        <div sample class="appls myElement" ng-repeat="app in appData">
            <a href=#/applications/{{app.uri}}>
                <div>
                    <img ng-src="{{app.imageS}}"/>
                    {{app.name}}
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
</script>
```

JS -

```
app.directive('sample', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        element.on('click', function () {
            $(element).trigger("myEvent.sample");
        });
    },
};
});

$(document).ready(function () {

$('img').on('dragstart', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });

$(".myElement").on("myEvent.sample", function (e) {
    alert('clicked!');
    console.log("made it");
});

});
```

I'd like to think that I am using directives correctly, but I am fairly new to Angular and I'm sure I'm using it incorrectly with Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to your `document.ready(..)` function.

```
console.log('sample count: '+$(".myElement").length);
```

I think you'll find that it prints `sample count: 1` to the console.

In your template you have

```
<div sample class="appls myElement" ng-repeat="app in appData">
```

The `ng-repeat` directive creates additional DOM elements, but this happens during an Angular digest cycle. Which is happening *after* the document ready is executed.

If you want to broadcast custom jQuery events from AngularJS. Pick a DOM element that you know exists.

In your directive change to this

```
  $('body').trigger('myEvent.sample', $(element));
```

Now you can catch the event elsewhere in your JavaScript.

```
  $('body').on('myEvent.sample',function(event, element){
      console.log("made it");
      console.log(element); // the argument for the event.
  });
```

Comment: When you say I should destroy the event, I should do this in my controller, correct?

Comment: @Xogle ignore that and I removed it from my answer. When you bind an event listener to something outside of the directive. You have to unbind it when $destroy is called, but I forgot you were calling `trigger` and not binding anything.